# Is paste a special argument in plotmath expressions?

Tags: r, graphics, syntax, plot, plotmath

When supplying a `plotmath` expression to a plot title I thought that `paste` worked just like `paste`, but now I am not sure. Is it a special argument to `plotmath` functions? In plotmath `paste()` behaves like `paste0()` and `paste0` is quoted directly, whilst the `sep` argument of `paste()` is ignored, but not quoted in the expression. How is `paste()` interpreted? See the four examples below:

```
#  Data to plot
x <- seq( 55 , 70 , length = 2001 )
probs <- dexp( x , rate = 5 / 60  )
s <- sample( x , 10000 , prob = probs , repl = TRUE )


#  Some plots
par(mfrow = c(2,2) )
#1)  paste() behaves like paste0() here
hist( s , breaks = 30 , 
    main = expression( paste( "1: Sampling of" , Phi , "Distribution" ) ) ,
    xlab = "No spaces in title using paste()" , axes = F )

#2)  add spaces in the expression where they are needed
hist( s , breaks = 30 , 
    main = expression( paste( "2: Sampling of "  , Phi , " Distribution" ) ) ,
    xlab = "Single spaces in titles: paste() behaves like paste0()" , axes = F )

#3)  Don't put spaces, use a sep argument - ignored
hist( s , breaks = 30 , 
    main = expression( paste( "3: Sampling of"  , Phi , "Distribution" , sep = " " ) ) ,
    xlab = "No spaces using paste(), `sep` argument is ignored but not quoted in expression" , axes = F )

#4)  paste0 is not recognised
hist( s , breaks = 30 , 
    main = expression( paste0( "4: Sampling of " , Phi , " Distribution" ) ) ,
    xlab = "paste0() not recognised" , axes = F )
```

[image]

Comment: you may need `eval(expression(paste...))` --- at least that's what I did at the console level to return a char string.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that worked with say my sample code for plot 1? I find that R instead searches for the object `Phi` (Phi is a plotmath feature and should be interpreted as the symbol).

Comment: Hmph. I seem to remember a tutorial on how to do exactly what you want, but have no clue where it was.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Your comment betrays a fundamental misunderstanding of plotmath expressions. If you want a character string to be printed to a plot device with `text` you just enclose it in quotes. If you want to concatenate expressions or strings with displayed spaces use `~`. The example using `paste` and an interposed " " in the ?plotmath page doesn't really need that function, and could be more compactly written as: `text(8, 3, expression(frac(1, sigma*sqrt(2*pi))~~e^{ frac( -(x-mu)^2, 2*sigma^2)}),  cex = 1.2)`

Comment: @DWin, well, I *did* say I'd completely forgotten -and that included the `?plotmath` page :-) .  But thanks for reminding me to rtfm before commenting; I deserved that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed `paste` in plotmath is not the classic `paste`. See `?plotmath`:

> paste(x, y, z)     juxtapose x, y, and z

`paste` in the context of `plotmath` doesn't have a `sep` argument.

And in the source code `plotmath.c` you can see that `paste` is redefined:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
*
* Code for Concatenate Expressions
*
*/

static int ConcatenateAtom(SEXP expr)
{
    return NameAtom(expr) && NameMatch(expr, "paste");
}

static BBOX RenderConcatenate(SEXP expr, int draw, mathContext *mc,
                         pGEcontext gc, pGEDevDesc dd)
{
    BBOX bbox = NullBBox();
    int i, n;

    expr = CDR(expr);
    n = length(expr);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bbox = CombineBBoxes(bbox, RenderElement(CAR(expr), draw, mc, gc, dd));
        if (i != n - 1)
         bbox = RenderItalicCorr(bbox, draw, mc, gc, dd);
        expr = CDR(expr);
    }
    return bbox;
}
```

It is dispatched later in the file:

```
static BBOX RenderFormula(SEXP expr, int draw, mathContext *mc,
                         pGEcontext gc, pGEDevDesc dd)
{
    SEXP head = CAR(expr);

    ....
    else if (ConcatenateAtom(head))
        return RenderConcatenate(expr, draw, mc, gc, dd);
    ....
```

(That being said I know nothing about C so I may be wrong on that one)

Comment: +1 Very interesting thanks! I think that answers my question.